# Validacion en Formularios reactivos, Setear SetValidators a no requerido

Tags: angularjs-2.0, formularios, reactjs, validación

Buenas tardes, tengo un problema, he quemado todas las naves y no logro salir del embrollo, el tema es al cambio de validaciones de campos en un reacive form basado en el comportamiento de un grupo de campos. estoy creando una recetas, es un formulario con uan cabecera con varios campos y un subgrupo de campos que se repiten como filas,

```
cod barra | producto | cantidad | dias de vigencia |+|
```

estos son campos a rellenar y en primera instancia son required.
ejemplo

```
cod barra | producto | cantidad | dias de vigencia |+| (inputs para agregar datos)

0025 ------| amoxi..---|-----10-----|------ 5 --------------|-|
```

(muestra los datos recien cargados y puedo eliminarlos presionando -, todo estos solo en el frond end, aun sin persistir en la base de datos.)

estoy usando formbuilder

```
  this.recetaform = this.fb.group({
  paciente: ['', [<any>Validators.required, <any>Validators.minLength(7), <any>Validators.maxLength(9)]],
  femision: [this.fechaHoy(), [<any>Validators.required]],
  servicio: ['', [<any>Validators.required]],
  idServicio: ['', [<any>Validators.required]],
  turno: ['', [<any>Validators.required]],
  prestador: ['', [<any>Validators.required]],
  idPrestador: ['', [<any>Validators.required]],
  diagnostico: ['', [<any>Validators.required]],
  idDiagnostico: ['', [<any>Validators.required]],
  productofgn: this.fb.group({
    cb: [''],
    producto: ['', [<any>Validators.required]],
    lote: ['', [<any>Validators.required]],
    cant: ['', [<any>Validators.required]],
    dias: ['', [<any>Validators.required]],
  })
});
```

la idea es que al cargar la primera tupla (esto se almacena en un array de objetos mediante push) cambiar el validador required de los campos:

producto, lote, cant y dias

a no requerido. y que si borro esa tupla creada, me devuelva los valores required que tenia inicialmente.

yo lo habia pensado contando los elementos en el vector de objetos que guarda estos datos, pero me di cuenta que no se donde controlar , si el el cambio del formulario es decir con

```
this.recetaform.valueChanges.subscribe(data => this.unafuncion());
```

o cuando agrego o quito elementos al vector. se que ahora esta mi dato de interes, no logro relacionarlo con los cambios.

estuve viendo SetValidators segun muestra este tutorial:

https://coursetro.com/posts/code/66/Angular-4-Reactive-Forms-Tutorial

pero en este es en base a al cambio de un campo con contenido booleano que realiza el control y en base a eso cambia las validaciones.

de esta menera:

```
ngOnInit() {
this.rForm.get('validate').valueChanges.subscribe(

  (validate) => {

      if (validate == '1') {
          this.rForm.get('name').setValidators([Validators.required, Validators.minLength(3)]);
          this.titleAlert = 'You need to specify at least 3 characters';
      } else {
          this.rForm.get('name').setValidators(Validators.required);
      }
      this.rForm.get('name').updateValueAndValidity();

  });
```

}

alguna mano?, espero ser claro, es mi primer posteo en stackOverflow, y veo que no esta n sencilo trasnmitir una idea sin todo el codigo. :(

Comment: Buenas, no se si entendi al completo tu pregunta pero creo que algo pille, no puedes crearte dos métodos, uno para añadir los required validators y otro para borrarlos, y dependiendo de si el ítem está dentro o fuera del array, llamar a esas funciones?

Comment: si, pero en realidad lo que necesito es solo que al encontrar un elemento del array quite la validación, le hemos resuelto de otra manera, pero quería ser estricto con la validación pero bueno, por ahora funciona. me da tiempo para seguir investigando como hacerlo correctamente y refactorizar. lo hemos resuelto solo con lógica y no dependiendo de los validadores. es un poco magra la documentación al respecto.  saludos.

Comment: Creo que la documentacion oficial de Angular es de las mejores que hay, sin embargo, sigo sin entender bien cosas como "lo que necesito es solo que al encontrar un elemento del array quite la validación" de todas formas si te funciona, bravo ;)